# Getting key and value pairs from a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable

I want to store diameter of euro coins inside a class and using a method in that class to get value(worth) of a coin by its diameter.

First I am not sure using a class and building its dictionary on initializaition is a good idea or not so If you know a better way please let me now.

Second, I wrote the code for this class like this:

```
class EuroCoinSpecs
{
    public Dictionary<double, decimal> CoinsDiameters;

    public EuroCoinSpecs()
    {
        CoinsDiameters = new Dictionary<double, decimal>
                        {
                            {25.75, 2.00m},
                            {23.25, 1.00m},
                            {24.25, 0.50m},
                            {22.25, 0.20m},
                            {19.75, 0.10m},
                            {21.25, 0.05m},
                            {18.75, 0.02m},
                            {16.25, 0.01m}
                        };
    }

    public decimal GetValueForDiameter(double diameter)
    {
        return CoinsDiameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == diameter);
    }
}
```

The problem is the code in `GetValueForDiameter` does not compile because of this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<double,decimal>' to 'decimal'
```

I tried different ways but it does not want to work. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have given the way of fetching using `FirstOrDefault` - but it seems pretty pointless to me. Why not *use* the fact that you've got a dictionary, which is designed to perform key lookups for you?

```
public decimal GetValueForDiameter(double diameter)
{
    decimal ret;
    // This will set ret to 0m if the key isn't found.
    CoinsDiameters.TryGetValue(diameter, out ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Having said all of that, I would *strongly* recommend that you don't perform equality operations on `double` values like this. It'll work okay in the cases you've given, but as soon as you start using any sort of arithmetic, you could well end up causing problems.

Answer (score 4):

`FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == diameter)` selects an item from the dictionnary, which is a `KeyValuePair`. And the method expects a `decimal` to be returned !

You have to return the value or the selected pair. Something like this:

```
return CoinsDiameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == diameter).Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your call to `FirstOrDefault` is returning a `KeyValuePair<double, decimal>`. You'll need to return the `Value` property:

```
return CoinsDiameters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == diameter).Value;
```

Secondly, an initialization list is fine in this case, though I'd consider storing this data in a config file and reading it at runtime (so that future updates don't need a recompile).

Thirdly, is the diameter truly unique? If you repeat a key:

1. Your initialization list will fail as it invokes `Add`; you cannot `Add` the same key twice to a dictinoary
2. You'll lose the previous value in the dictionary (if you're not using `Add`, but the indexer setter)

If this is the case, consider using a `Dictionary<double, List<decimal>>`. If you are grouping them in this way, consider wrapping each group to make your code more readable.

```
class CoinGroup { public double Diameter {...} public ICollection<Coin> Coins { ... } }
```

This way, you can give more meta data about the coin as well (in the `Coin` class)

```
class Coin { public string Local {...} public decimal Value {...} }
```

Just some thoughts I had.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an answer to your "is it a good idea" query than your actual, nuts and bolts code question:

Personally, I would suggest that you make a Type called Coin that has a double property and a decimal property.  It's a mild example, but a tendency to manage concepts as ad-hoc collections of primitives is a code smell called "Primitive Obsession".

If you make a coin type, you can keep a list or enumeration or something else that's easier than a dictionary to maintain and use.

Comment: Thanks, is what you said  true if there is only 8 type of coins avilable in the Europe!?

Comment: It's less of a question of how many of the type there are than it is how many properties there are of the type.  Imagine if you decided to add another decimal for the weight of the coin along with an enum for the material it's made out of.  Suddenly, your dictionary representation is ballooning into three parallel dictionaries (or something).  That's the slippery slope you wind up on with maintaining primitives in this fashion.